# Whole block device named xvda1, xvda2 instead of xvda, xvdb

Tags: linux, xen, block-device, paravirtualization

I am working on a VM that was set up for me in a public cloud. It's running under the Xen hypervisor in paravirtualized mode and has two virtual disks. So I expect the virtual disk block devices to be named `xvda` and `xvdb`. However, the way this machine has been set up, the block devices are named `xvda1` and `xvda2`. Mind you, these aren't partition names. They are names of the whole block devices. Under `/sys/block` there are `xvda1` and `xvda2` directories. Normally, I'd expect to see `xvda` and `xvdb` under `/sys/block`, because as [documented here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devices.txt) that's how Xen virtual disk devices (whole disks) are supposed to be named.

Looking in `/proc/partitions` there are only two entries: `xvda1` and `xvda2`. Under `/dev` there are also only `/dev/xvda1` and `/dev/xvda2` (no `/dev/xvda` or `/dev/xvdb`). I also looked at the udev rules to see if the devices had been intentionally renamed, but could find nothing under `/etc/udev/rules.d` that is responsible for this.

Are these legitimate names for these devices, or has the system administrator made some kind of misconfiguration? The names certainly seem to be at odds with the Linux kernel's device.txt documentation. Or is this normal for a Xen paravirtualized VM?

Comment: What does `fdisk -l` show?

Comment: @ewwhite The output from `fdisk -l` is consistent with the rest. It shows two disks named `/dev/xvda1` and `/dev/xvda2`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a configuration issue as such. Xen allow for virtual disks to be mapped to partition names.
I used to do it that way in the past but reverted to a more classic approach later on for several reasons.
As far as I remember,  you use the vdisks as partitions or even add partitions on top of it. You would end up with something like `xvda1p1` iirc.